# RF pickup noise through coaxial cables and connectors

Tags: rf, noise, antenna, coax

We use RF antenna to transmit RF power in the near field regime. The typical wavelength is ~ 10 MHz whereas the antenna itself is only a few cm long(3 loops of a copper wire). We see that for a power of about 2 watt, all the BNC and sma cables and the connectors from other electronics equipment pickup lots of noise. The frequency of the pickup noise is not same as the RF frequency though (~30 Hz, so we can't filter this out for our experiment). My question is, can such a small antenna(compared to the wavelength of the RF) of this size emit EM waves and is there any way to reduce this pickup noise? We have tried to eliminate all possible ground loops and used good quality coax cables. Any input and suggestions are most welcome.

Comment: Have you verified that you're not also generating harmonics?

Comment: Yes, we verified that, the power is extremely low in the other harmonics.

Comment: Having the noise or interference signal well separated from the desired signal should make it easier to filter out, not harder.

Comment: Probably goes without saying, but you should rule out that the ~30Hz isn't actually ~50Hz.

Comment: No, we checked, it's not 50hz noise.

Comment: Why can't you remove 30 HZ? - do you mean it is 30 Hz difference / offset ? 
eg is it 10,000,000 +/- 30 Hz ?

Comment: No, it's a 30hz noise, not difference.

Answer (score 2):

1. Even a small antenna, relative to the wavelength, can radiate significantly in the [near field](https://engineerstutor.com/2018/08/17/near-and-far-fields-of-antenna-radiation-antenna-communications/) mode. This is reactive radiation, e.g., inducing currents as a transformer, or by capacitance. [Near-field radiation falls off exponentially](https://www.wtamu.edu/%7Ecbaird/BLecture6.pdf), rather than according to 1/r<sup>2</sup>, so it only applies when very close. (In optics, this is considered the [evanescent field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evanescent_field).)
2. There are [dual- and even quad-shielded cables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evanescent_field) designed for that specific need. For example, in a broadcast studio near a transmitter, extra shielding is needed. Though you apparatus is low powered, if it's closely-coupled, you might need additional shielding.
3. You an also interpose a metallic (and/or [ferrite](https://www.djmelectronics.com/rf-absorber.html), at higher frequencies) cover to separate the sensitive electronics and cabling from the signal.
4. Be sure that the only source of interference is the cable. **All** openings in equipment, e.g., for a display or meter, should be covered by mesh. **All** connectors should be effectively grounded, with lock-washers to cut though any surface oxidation. Any power cable should have [bypass feed-through capacitors](http://lcamic.com/blog/2015/11/11/whats-feed-through-capacitors/), and possibly a series inductor, as well.